# flutter: custom painter not repainting even though the shouldRepaint() returns true

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, ffi

I'm testing flutter FFI by getting colour data from C/C++ side and painting the screen using `CustomPainter`.

But to my surprise, even though I set the painter to always repaint, the `paint()` function is only called twice.

### Code

```dart
class _ColorViewPainter extends CustomPainter {
  Color clrBackground;

  _ColorViewPainter({
    this.clrBackground = Colors.black
  });

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_ColorViewPainter old) => true;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    print("paint: start");

    final color = ffiGetColor().ref;

    final r = color.r;
    final g = color.g;
    final b = color.b;

    print("color: $r, $g, $b");

    final paint = Paint()
        ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
        ..strokeWidth = 1.0
        ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, r, g, b)
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final width = size.width;
    final height = size.height;
    final content = Offset(0.0, 0.0) & Size(width, height);
    canvas.drawRect(content, paint);

    print("paint: end");
  }
}
```

The `ffiGetColor()` function simply retrieves a colour RGB struct from C/C++ side. I can see the screen being updated twice and the log says:

```
I/flutter (12096): paint: start
I/flutter (12096): color: 255, 0, 0
I/flutter (12096): paint: end
I/flutter (12096): paint: start
I/flutter (12096): color: 0, 255, 0
I/flutter (12096): paint: end
I/Surface (12096): opservice is null false
```

But that's it. Even though I clearly want it to repaint with `shouldRepaint`. flutter failed to do so.

What's wrong?

here is my environment

```sh
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.18.0-dev.5.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-CA)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✗] Cannot determine if IntelliJ is installed
    ✗ Directory listing failed
[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: check `repaint` parameter passed to `CustomPainter` constructor

Comment: *"But that's it. Even though I clearly want it to repaint with shouldRepaint. flutter failed to do so."* - so did you check when `shouldRepaint` is called?

Comment: @pskink good point. `shouldRepaint` was only called twice. I'll take a look at the listenable idea first and report back. Thanks!

Comment: @pskink thanks for you tips. I now have a new problem regarding update rate. Would you have a moment to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62859088/dart-flutter-custompaint-updates-at-a-lower-rate-than-valuenotifiers-value-upd ?? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @pskink 's tips, I managed to make my CustomPainter repaint continuously, although it's still not perfect.

See [dart/flutter: CustomPaint updates at a lower rate than ValueNotifier's value update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62859088/dart-flutter-custompaint-updates-at-a-lower-rate-than-valuenotifiers-value-upd)

Because there is still an update rate problem with the current solution, I'm just reporting what I've got briefly:

I basically have to construct a notifier and assign ffi-retrieved values to it at a proper location via polling.

```dart
// in initState() of State class
_notifier = ValueNotifier<NativeColor>(ffiGetColor().ref);

...

// in a timer method
_notifier.value = ffiGetColor().ref;
```

Then with `CustomPaint`, bind notifier to repaint in its constructor

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

      ...


        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: _ColorViewPainter(
              context: context,
              notifier: _notifier,
              ...
          )
        )
    );
  }
```

```dart
class _ColorViewPainter extends CustomPainter {
  ValueNotifier<NativeColor> notifier;
  BuildContext context;
  Color clrBackground;

  _ColorViewPainter({this.context, this.notifier, this.clrBackground})
    : super(repaint: notifier) {
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_ColorViewPainter old) {
    print('should repaint');
    return true;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    print("paint: start");
    final r = notifier.value.r;
    final g = notifier.value.g;
    final b = notifier.value.b;
    print("color: $r, $g, $b");
    final paint = Paint()
        ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
        ..strokeWidth = 1.0
        ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, r, g, b)
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final width = size.width;
    final height = size.height;
    final content = Offset(0.0, 0.0) & Size(width, height);
    canvas.drawRect(content, paint);
    print("paint: end");
  }

}
```

### GOTCHAS

`ValueNotifier` relies on the following conditions to be able to fire up notification to its listeners

- The value type it binds to has defined the `operator ==`
- The `ValueNotifier`'s value field, which your data object of choice binds to, **gets explicitly reassigned** with a NEW data object on changes.

This is crucial when we bind the notifier to a custom class. With a custom class, we must

- overload its `operator ==`.
- ASSIGN a NEW object to `ValueNotifier<MyClass>.value` instead of modifying the data object's value by calling its own regular methods.

Otherwise the `CustomPaint`'s `paint()` will not be called on desired changes.

To give an example, this custom class is not qualified to bind with a `ValueNotifier`, because there is no overloaded `operator==`:

```dart
class MyClass {
  int prop = 0;

  void changeValue(newValue) {
    prop = newValue;
  }

}
```

To give another example, assume we have a custom class:

```dart
class MyClass {
  int prop = 0;

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant MyClass other) {
    return other is MyClass && prop != other. prop;
  }

  void changeValue(newValue) {
    prop = newValue;
  }

}
```

This will work:

```dart
class _MyViewState extends State<MyView> {
  ValueNotifier<MyClass> notifier;
  Timer _timer;

  ....

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    notifier = ValueNotifier<MyClass>(MyClass());
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 10), _updateData);
  }

  _updateData(Timer t) {
     var myObj = MyClass(newValue);
     notifier.value = myObj;
  }

}
```

But this won't work.

```dart
class _MyViewState extends State<MyView> {
  ValueNotifier<MyClass> notifier;
  Timer _timer;

  ....

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    notifier = ValueNotifier<MyClass>(MyClass());
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 10), _updateData);
  }


  _updateData(Timer t) {
     var newValue = getNewValueSomewhere();
     notifier.value.changeValue(newValue);
  }
```

Comment: The best answer from all over the internet on this subject. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JavaRunner glad to have helped :)